# Tensorflow cant find GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I reviewed all the relevant questions but none of them seem to answer mine,

I have `Python 3.7.4 64bit` installed on a Windows 10 machine.
I am using Tensorflow 2.1.
I have the latest NVIDIA drivers for my `NVidia 1080 Ti` card 
 - `Version 442.19 - WHQL, Release Date: Feb 03, 2020`
 - `Compute Capability: 6.1`

I've installed `cuDNN v7.6.4 (September 27, 2019), for CUDA 10.1`
I've uninstalled `TensorFlow 2.1` and re-installed it.
I've uninstalled TensorFlow and installed `Tensorflow-gpu 2.1`.
I've installed `Visual C++ Build Tools 2019`
 - `Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable`
 - `Microsoft Build Tools 2019`

When I list local devices, only the CPU is there.

> ```
> print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
> print('-' * 10)
> print(tf.config.list_logical_devices())
> ```

yields:

```
--------------------------------------------------
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
----------
[LogicalDevice(name='/device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
--------------------------------------------------
```

Nothing seems to work.